# What went wrong with my Washer and how do I fix it?

Tags: washing-machine

For about a month or more my to-loaded washer was getting more and more off balance.  Then it started ticking and not spinning, then recently it stopped spinning altogether.
Everything else still works...it just doesn't spin (which basically means it's useless).

I'm pretty sure that means a belt went out or something but I am a home improvement newb (and this site may be the best thing to ever happen to me....excluding my wife of course)

Comment: is that `top-loaded`?

Comment: Luckily washing machines are relatively simple. If you see anything interesting, post a picture here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that a small plastic piece in the motor broke.  It was going to cost quite a bit to replace because it made the transmission not work.  The part was cheap but the time would have cost around $150-$180 (this is a family friend doing the work).
Found another washer for $250 down from $380 and bought that instead.

Answer (score 6):

Does it sound like a motor is still running in there when you turn it on?  My first guess would be that the belt that connects the motor to the drum either broke or is slipping.  If that's the case, it should be a pretty easy fix (replace the belt).  If not, then it's probably a bad motor.

Answer (score 1):

with the little detail in your question, I'd look at several things.  first, remove front cover.  Check the four rubber stabilizer bands located at the top of the drum. If some are broken or missing, excessive vibration will stop the spin cycle. Does the water pump out of the drum completely? OK? If there is water still in the drum, the spin cycle will not activate. And also take a look at the belt at the bottom of the drum connection to the motor.

Comment: if there is water in the drum at the very beginning of the spin cycle, check the inlet of the water pump for a blockage of lint or a bit of material etc. that is slowing the draining of the drum.